# apply url to retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm writting a retrofit demo.
I have to use "https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/oauth2/access_token?appid=APPID&secret=SECRET&code=CODE&grant_type=authorization_code" to get code.

when writing rest, I do it like this:

```
public interface WXService {

    @GET("/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code")
    Observable<AccessTokenModel> getAccessToken(@Query("appid") String appId,
                                          @Query("secret") String secretId,
                                          @Query("code") String code);

}


public class WXRest {
    private static final String WXBaseUrl = "https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/oauth2/";
    private WXService mWXService;

    public WXRest() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WXBaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        mWXService = retrofit.create(WXService.class);
    }

    public void getAccessToken(String code) {
        mWXService.getAccessToken(Constants.APP_ID, Constants.SECRET_ID, code)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<AccessTokenModel>() {
            @Override
            public void call(AccessTokenModel accessTokenModel) {
                Log.e("WX", "accessToken:" + accessTokenModel.accessToken);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

but I got an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
>   rx.Observable

I think it's the way i transform the url wrong.But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: its may be becuase you are using / in both `WXBaseUrl` and `@Get`,remove `/` in get request beginning like this `@GET("access_token?grant_type=authorization_code")`

Comment: I have tried. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `Call<AccessTokenModel> getAccessToken(....);` in your API Service

Answer (score 2):

i think you should include adapter-rxjava lib to your gradle dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
```

and then add call adapter factory to your retrofit builder

```
public WXRest() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WXBaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        mWXService = retrofit.create(WXService.class);
    }
```